# why my application doesn't work when I want to create buttons dynamically in android?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an android application and I have a little problem.
I want to make ten buttons dynamically. If I set Button text directly, it works and creates ten buttons very well.

```
LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lil);
for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
    Button B = new Button(this);
    B.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,10);
    B.setText("1");
    ll.addView(B); 
}
```

But, when I try to set text like below, it makes only one button without any text!

```
String BtnText = "";
String temp = "";
String []DD = new String [3];
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lil);
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
    temp = SplitData[i];
    DD = temp.split("/");
    BtnText = DD[0].toString();
    Button B = new Button(this);
    B.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,10);
    B.setText(BtnText);
    ll.addView(B);          
}
```

Surprisingly, I debugged my application line by line and couldn't find any problem. Everything works well. I don't have any exception. Do you have any suggestion?

Complete Code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {    
    String WebData = ""; // Data from Web Server    
    int DC = 0; // Data Co0unter    
    String[] SplitData = new String[10]; //Split Data array 

    protected void DataCollector(String ReciveData) {       
        WebData = ReciveData;   
    }

    private void Spliter() {    
        SplitData = WebData.split("-");   
    }

    private void CreateUI() {
        String BtnText = "";
        Button B = null;
        //String temp = "";     
        //String []DD = new String [3];
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll);
        try {
            for (String aSplitData : SplitData) {           
                BtnText = aSplitData.split("/")[0];
                B = new Button(this);
                B.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,10);          
                B.setText(BtnText);
                ll.addView(B);          
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("Error : ",ex.toString());
        }
    }   

    class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String...Urls) {
            try {
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;                     
                URL myUrl = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:80/mob1/Default.aspx");        
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)myUrl.openConnection();      
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));         
                String temp = "";        
                while ((temp=in.readLine()) != null) {              
                    DataCollector(temp);            
                }               
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();     
                }                               
            }           
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("error",e.toString());
                return "1";
            }
            return "1"; 
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String Result) {
            //        
        }
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        new RetrieveFeedTask().execute();   
        Spliter();
        CreateUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `SplitData[]` ? <--- free tip : that's the source of the problem.

Comment: no it is not !! this is an array , it has data and i use this data !

Comment: And what data does it (i.e. the `SplitData` array) have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your very first problem** here is that you don't wait the end of the execution of `RetrieveFeedTask` to create the ui. So you will build your ui on empty data.

Solution : use the `onPostExecute` to manipulate your data (i.e. `Splitter()`) and draw your ui (i.e. `CreateUI()`)

**Your next problem** is probably here :

```
 while((temp=in.readLine())!=null)
        {               
            DataCollector(temp);            
        }
```

It is really strange code : it will simply replace the local variable `WebData` with the last line received. (I have no idea why you do that....)

**Third problem** :

IMHO, if you want better responses when you post your code here: try to make it more readable and follow basic java code style conventions like this one : "instance variable and locale variable starting with a lower case".

(and also try to use more explicit names for your variables : `DD` is not meaningful, use `button` instead of `B` ... )

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned your code and fixed a bunch of issues.

1. never use a fixed loop, always loop over the array with it's max length. Otherwise you are just calling for trouble.
2. Only declare the Button variable once and change it's value as needed.
3. You don't need temp or DD, you can do it in one line
4. I created and filled SplitData with some data you expect to see for it to work
5. I also corrected your code-style, to make it readable. You should really think about cleaning your code before posting it. :)

This will generate 10 buttons below each other with text from SplitData.

layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

onCreate:

```
//fill SplitData
String[] SplitData = new String [10];
for (int i = 0; i < SplitData.length; i++)
    SplitData[i] = "Button" + i + "/other/stuff";

//your original code, cleaned
Button b = null;
String BtnText = "";
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
for (String aSplitData : SplitData) {
    BtnText = aSplitData.split("/")[0];
    b = new Button(this);
    b.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10);
    b.setText(BtnText);
    ll.addView(b);
}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: `Only declare the Button variable once and change it's value as needed, otherwise the garbage collector will have to run amok for all the variables you dismissed.` I'd love to see your elaboration about this.

Comment: `You don't need temp or DD, you can do it in one line, without reserving memory for variables` Yes, this is indeed a major memory flaw ... no, not really.

Comment: "Only declare the Button variable once and change it's value as needed, otherwise the garbage collector will have to run amok for all the variables you dismissed." This is nonsense. "You don't need temp or DD, you can do it in one line, without reserving memory for variables" Although it's true that they are unnecessary and doing without them is *cleaner*, using variables doesn't affect the memory usage.

Comment: And if you correct his "code-style", then you might also correct his naming style.

Comment: @Tom as I was typing a justification of what I thought when I wrote that statement I slapped myself on the forehead. We still hold a reference to the button in ll, which is why the garbage collector won't clean it in both cases.
As I understood it every variable takes up space in memory, if you have less variables, you use less memory. (arguably only a minor amount of memory, but still) His original code created 10 button variables, which had to be cleaned and removed by the gc, or am I completely of the wagon? Anyways, I will edit my answer.

Comment: let me use your advice , i will tell you the resualt . i love you man tnx for help ...  see you soon

Comment: @show-p1984 You might want to read this: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/56585/where-do-you-declare-variables-the-top-of-a-method-or-when-you-need-them (it is about your second point). There is no reason to increase the variable scope by moving them outside the loop.

Comment: it doesnt work . i changed my code as you said but it doesnt work . also i debugged the code but i couldnt find any Exception !!!

Comment: @Bigbrother I edited my answer with a screenshot. It works just fine.

Comment: @Elltz because his original question was far shorter than it is now. Have a look at the revisions.